# Color Logic - Find the rule

Tags: pattern, visual, no-computers

**Find the rule specified in the image below.**

[image: logic]

<sub>[(Where I got it)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.gromozeka1980.caterpillar_logic&hl=en)</sub>

Comment: Just wondering: is this puzzle taken directly from Caterpillar Logic or merely inspired by it?

Comment: @Riley It was inspired by that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think I found the rule.

> There must be exactly one green tile per row, and there must be more tiles to the left of the green than to the right.

Answer (score -1):

Answer:

> If same color blocks comes side-by side, its allowed only once per line. Multiple times of same color blocks placing side-by-side in same line is not valid.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Puzzling SE! Take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour). Do you think you could put a spoiler >! on your answer? Also, it seems that your answer explains the left half of the picture, but not the right half. The labels "true" and "false" indicate that the left half follows the rule while the right half does not. But the lines on the right follow your rule.

Comment: It’s worse than that. If I understand this answer correctly, then the 6th row in the left (“True”) column fails to satisfy the rule.

Comment: @PeregrineRook It doesn't look like it to me. I think the problem is that only the fifth row in the false section fails this?