# Here's another Color Logic problem

Tags: pattern, visual, no-computers

**Find the rule specified in the image below.**

[image: logic]

*Note that the rule applies to each row independently so every "true" row is "true" by itself*

---

**If you are confused about these, here's an easy one:**

[image: logic easy]

Did you get it right? The answer to the puzzle above is:

> They must contain the color red.

Comment: Such complex shapes would allow for many possible patterns, especially given only 1 example - all of these would also be valid for the "easy" one: must contain 8 blue, or a red in its own row, or not a green in its own row, or green in only each of the first 4 columns or ... It might've been better to post multiple examples with fewer rows, columns and maybe colours.

Comment: You should specify whether the rule applies to every shape as a whole or to separate rows (so every "true" row is "true" by itself); or to separate columns. Or to what?

Comment: @NotThatGuy The rule has to do with each row individually, as evidenced by the [source](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.gromozeka1980.caterpillar_logic&hl=en) given in his [previous](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65575/color-logic-find-the-rule) color logic puzzle. Although, I do think this should be stated explicitly to avoid confusion.

Comment: Additional spacing between each row or maybe a number at the front of each would help make it clear that there are multiple examples rather than a single blob.  You could also box them off, similar to the [What is a ... word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.

Comment: I'm not sure this qualifies as [tag:logical-deduction]. In the accepted answer, I don't see anything *formally deduced* or proven from known facts. Rather, it appears to essentially be an educated guess. But perhaps I don't understand the tag correctly, not being a regular solver.

Comment: @jpmc26 You're right, it isn't [tag:logical-deduction]; tag removed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is:

> Each row has precisely two dark grey rectangles with an odd number of other-coloured rectangles between them

I got this by:

> Noticing that they stand out, which allowed me to find that there were two in each row, with a small modification for a couple of the False rows which also had two of those

Answer (score 11):

I think the answer is:

> Each row should contain dark grey color exactly two times.

Comment: Sorry, your rule does not satisfy. Check the right half. (2 and 6 contains exactly 2 dark greys)

Comment: yeah but not in each row, anyway u must be looking for diff soln!

Comment: This answer seems just as right as the accepted one (arguably even more "right" since the rule is simpler), which shows that the Q was too ambiguous.

Comment: If you look at the statement "Each row contains dark grey colour exactly two times" then it is true for the left image and false for the right one. If each row of the image is meant to be its own "puzzle" and you have just grouped them according to whether they are true or false then you should make that clearer in the question.