# Color Logic problem 3

Tags: pattern, visual, no-computers

**Find the rule specified in the image below.** Make sure the rule *fully* satisfies.

[image: is it enough?]

<sub>[Part two](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65612/heres-another-color-logic-problem) and [one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65575/color-logic-find-the-rule)</sub>

Comment: Are these all coming from the same caterpillar logic app?

Comment: @boboquack No, it's not.

Comment: Are each line verifying the logic independently?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't know if it's **the** rule, but I found **a** rule that satisfies both the true and false examples:

> If you divide the line in half, each half has at least one full light-blue square

Comment: Depending on how you handle rounding, your approach won't work correctly with False (2) and (3).

Comment: @Orphevs I don't think rounding applies, CaptainPlanet says "one **XXXX** xxxxx-xxxx square" where **XXXX** is the key word here.

Comment: @boboquack - nice inline spoilering, though it took me more than one re-read to get it :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about

> Each line must have at least 2 blue square with a limit of 2 consecutive color

Comment: False 2,3, and 7 match this rule though, meaning it cant be that.

Answer (score 1):

I think this pretty much fits:

> If there are more lightblue squares, than other colored ones in a line, the next line must be longer than the actual line, otherwise the next line must be 1 square shorter.

Comment: For these types of rule puzzles, I believe the lines need to be analyzed independently (that is, the rule needs to apply to each line in a vacuum)

Answer (score 0):

The rules are:

> There must be more than one blue square in a line, each half of a line containing atleast one blue square, and
>  not more than two blue squares should come together in a line.

Comment: I believe the idea is there is only **one** rule

Comment: @Jon.G just glue the rules with _**and**_...

Comment: IMHO rule 3. follows from 1. unless you meant 'each half'.

Answer (score -3):

> Rows of length two (2) cannot contain an orange square.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35405)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil If you consider the true and false as total grids that follow the rules, rather than collections of rows that each follow the rule, then this answer does identify one of the many, many possible rules to distinguish the grids. You could also view the question slightly differently as "do all rows in this group pass the rule?", in which case one failure would fail the whole category. Either way, this makes sense to me as a full answer, given that the question isn't explicit about how to interpret the grids. Admission: I made the same mistake initially.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil actually, logically this is a 100% airtight answer. You obviously have no sense of humour.