# Color Logic - Balance

Tags: pattern, visual

<sup>Inspired by [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65575/color-logic-find-the-rule)</sup>

---

Find the rule that each color chain on the left follows, but none on the right follow.

[image]

Raw text if you're colorblind or something (O = orange, Y = yellow, G = green, C = cyan):

Left:

```
COGGYCYOC
GYGYG
O
YYGGGGYYY
OC
GYO
GYYYGOG
OCGCOYO
CYOYOOY
GCGCGCGC
```

Right:

```
CC
GCYO
YYYYYOOOO
YCGOYCG
OYCGCY
GOC
CCCGYOO
OOY
CYOGYYCG
GOCOYOGGCO
```

If you want to see more cases, you may suggest up to 5 additional color chains, and I will sort them accordingly. As a rule of thumb, try to keep the length at $10$ blocks or less. You may suggest chains in [this chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82445/room-for-solving-rileys-puzzle).

Hint 1:

> If you reverse a chain, it will stay on the same side.

Hint 2:

> If you recolor all green to be orange, everything will stay on the same side.

Hint 3:

> The rule can be described as the equality of two quantities.

Comment: Another Hint Please?

Comment: @KhushrajRathod I will add a hint every 24 hours.

Comment: @Riley Maybe you can add a few 'caterpillar logic' style hints, i.e. we ask a combination and you put it on the left or on the right.

Comment: @rhsquared That could work. I'll do that in addition to hints I'm already giving. Not sure what the best way to do this is. Maybe each user is limited to 5 chains or something?

Comment: @Riley The first time 'caterpillar logic' puzzle was posted (can't remember who did it), (s)he gave us 3 tries in total, although the original game gives you unlimited attempts. It's your game.

Comment: @rhsquared I've added rules for suggesting more chains to the question.

Comment: just to clarify that last hint, is it that you swap, or just replace?

Comment: @micsthepick Edited for clarification.

Comment: @Riley Regarding Hint2, do you mean swapping the colours or just changing one of them according to the hint?

Comment: @rhsquared the terminology went from replace to recolour, so I assume that it is just changing one

Comment: @micsthepick Yes, that is correct. I thought I already commented telling rhsquared that I edited for clarification, but I guess it got deleted somehow. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯.

By the way, anyone can still suggest more chains. Surprised no one's taken advantage of this yet.

Comment: oh, I was not aware of that, is it a limit of 5 forever?, let's discuss in the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair)

Comment: Okay here's a suggestion of a new chain: YYYYYY. Which side does it go on?

Comment: here is a chatroom for asking for more examples: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82445/room-for-solving-rileys-puzzle

Comment: Does the question have anything to do with the colors themselves, or is it just about the pattern?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The set on the left is defined by

> having equal numbers of adjacent pairs of primary and secondary colored blocks.
>  First, treating O/G and Y/C as equivalent gives a picture like this: [image: simplification]
>  Counting a group of n as (n - 1) pairs, all the left sequences have the same number of primary and secondary pairs, while the right sequences differ.

Another way to phrase the answer:

> Count the number of primary and secondary colored blocks, weighting each end block .5 less than normal.  A solitary block's weighted zero, then.  The totals should be the same.

Comment: Yes, you got it! (And right after I added the bounty, too). I will accept this answer and award you the bounty. But not immediately so the question can receive more attention.

Answer (score 1):

This is just putting Mr. Fish's answer into mathematics:

> A sequence is valid if, and only if, it consists of two partitions of $n$ (the total number of blocks) into sub-sequences $a$ and $b$, with $\mid a\mid+\mid b\mid=n$. Furthermore, $\mid\operatorname{np}(a)-\operatorname{np}(b)\mid\le1$, where $\operatorname{np}(k)$ gives the number of parts of $k$. Also, the total sums of each part minus $1$ in each sequence are equal.